# Logging Hapi validation errors automatically

Tags: node.js, hapi.js, joi

I run a third-party application that uses Joi for validating outbound API responses.

A certain API call was returning a very generic 500 Internal Server Error with no error description in the API response nor output to the console.

I spent a while stepping through very circuitous package internals to finally find the ValidationError message that described what part of the output did not match the spec.

According to the [Hapi docs](https://hapi.dev/tutorials/validation/?lang=en_US#-input-validation), the default validation options use `failAction: 'error'` which is defined as `send an Internal Server Error (500) response`.

I think it's reasonable for a production server to return a sanitized 500 status code to the user agent, but I need to be able to diagnose the problem from the server side.

I could override the `failAction` for each route but that is an invasive change to third-party code. What other options do I have for logging globally?

Comment: Related issue:  https://github.com/hapijs/hapi/issues/4040

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up enabling [hapi-pino](https://github.com/pinojs/hapi-pino) which seemed to work out of the box.